# Is it possible to make the width of entry fit the width of window in gtk3?

Tags: css, c, graphics, gtk, gtk3

I know that we can set the size of entry with `gtk_entry_set_width_chars` but is there a way to make the width of entry fit the width of window in gtk3?

Edit:
Here are my code.

*bcc.h*:

```c
    #pragma once
    #include "gtk-layer-shell.h"
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>

    struct blake_control_center{
        GtkWindow *gtk_window;
        GtkWidget *layout;
        GtkEntryCompletion *entrycompletion;
        GtkListStore *liststore;
        GtkTreeIter iter;
        GtkWidget *entry;
        GtkApplication* app;

        struct bcc_config *config;
    };

    void bcc_load_styles(struct blake_control_center* bcc);
    void bcc_init(GtkApplication* app, void *_data);
    void bcc_entry_activated(GtkWidget *entry, gpointer data);
    void bcc_destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data);
 
    gboolean bcc_handle_key_press (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer user_data);
```

*bcc.c*:

```c
    #include "bcc.h"
    #include "config.h"
    #include <string.h>
    #include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>

    void bcc_init(GtkApplication* app, void *_data){
        (void)_data;
        struct blake_control_center bcc;
        bcc.app=app;
        GdkRectangle workarea = {0};
        gdk_monitor_get_workarea (gdk_display_get_primary_monitor (gdk_display_get_default()), &workarea);

        bcc.gtk_window = GTK_WINDOW (gtk_application_window_new (app));
        bcc.layout = gtk_layout_new(NULL, NULL);
        bcc.entrycompletion = gtk_entry_completion_new();
        bcc.liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
        bcc.entry = gtk_entry_new();

        gtk_layer_init_for_window (bcc.gtk_window);
        gtk_layer_set_layer (bcc.gtk_window, GTK_LAYER_SHELL_LAYER_BOTTOM);
        gtk_layer_auto_exclusive_zone_enable (bcc.gtk_window);

        gtk_list_store_append(bcc.liststore, &bcc.iter);
        gtk_list_store_set(bcc.liststore, &bcc.iter, 0, "Fedora", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(bcc.liststore, &bcc.iter);
        gtk_list_store_set(bcc.liststore, &bcc.iter, 0, "Sabayon", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(bcc.liststore, &bcc.iter);
        gtk_list_store_set(bcc.liststore, &bcc.iter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(bcc.liststore, &bcc.iter);
        gtk_list_store_set(bcc.liststore, &bcc.iter, 0, "SimplyMEPIS", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(bcc.liststore, &bcc.iter);
        gtk_list_store_set(bcc.liststore, &bcc.iter, 0, "Debian", -1);

        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(bcc.gtk_window), bcc.layout);
        gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW (bcc.gtk_window), FALSE);
        gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (bcc.gtk_window), workarea.width, workarea.height-200);
        gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW (bcc.gtk_window), 0,0);
        gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (bcc.gtk_window), 0);
        gtk_layer_set_anchor(bcc.gtk_window, 0, TRUE);// 
        gtk_layer_set_anchor(bcc.gtk_window, 1, TRUE);// 
        gtk_layer_set_anchor(bcc.gtk_window, 2, TRUE);// 
        gtk_layer_set_anchor(bcc.gtk_window, 3, FALSE);// 

        gtk_entry_completion_set_model (GTK_ENTRY_COMPLETION(bcc.entrycompletion), GTK_TREE_MODEL(bcc.liststore));
        gtk_entry_completion_set_text_column (GTK_ENTRY_COMPLETION(bcc.entrycompletion), 0);
        gtk_entry_set_completion(GTK_ENTRY(bcc.entry), bcc.entrycompletion);
    
        g_signal_connect(GTK_ENTRY(bcc.entry), "activate", G_CALLBACK(bcc_entry_activated), app);
        g_signal_connect(bcc.gtk_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(bcc_destroy), NULL);
        g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bcc.entry), "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK (bcc_handle_key_press),NULL);
    
        gtk_entry_set_width_chars(GTK_ENTRY(bcc.entry),170);

        gtk_layout_put(GTK_LAYOUT(bcc.layout), bcc.entry, 0, 0);

        bcc_load_styles(&bcc);
        gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET (bcc.gtk_window));
    }

    gboolean bcc_handle_key_press (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer user_data){
        printf("%d\n",event->keyval);
        return FALSE;
    }

    void bcc_load_styles(struct blake_control_center* bcc){
        GtkCssProvider *provider;
        GdkDisplay *display;
        GdkScreen *screen;
        bcc->config=calloc(1, sizeof(bcc->config));
        bcc_config_load(bcc->config);

        provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
        display = gdk_display_get_default ();
        screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
        gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

        GError *error = 0;

        gtk_css_provider_load_from_file(provider, g_file_new_for_path (bcc->config->css_file), &error);
        g_object_unref (provider);
    }

    void bcc_entry_activated(GtkWidget *entry, gpointer data)
    {   
        const gchar *cmd=gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry));
        if (!strcmp(cmd,"q")){
            g_application_quit(data);
        }
        g_print("Entry text: '%s'\n", cmd);
    }

    void bcc_destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
    {
        gtk_main_quit();
    }
```

styles.css:

```css
window {
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    border : 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
grid{
    background-color: rgb(44, 18, 18);
}
entry{
    background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
    font-size: 14px;
    color:aquamarine;
    font-family: Verdana;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-width: 0px;
}
entry .view {
    background-color: blue;
 }
 
 entry .view .cell {
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
 }
```

I did not put `main.c` and `config.h` as they have nothing related to the question.

Comment: What is the problematic code? Could you please supply an reproducible example please?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "fit the window size"? Do you mean that the entry should take all space from the left window border to the right window border?

Comment: @BobMorane Thanks, I did some edit to the question. I wonder if we can fit the width of entry with the width of window without carfully adding number of characters with `gtk_entry_set_width_chars`.

Comment: I was able to compile and run your example (which does not use `gtk_entry_set_width_chars`). The entry takes up the whole window. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake of thinking that any example would do and copies one from internet. I will put my own code now.

Comment: @BobMorane I understand now that it is automatically ok when the container is a gtk_window. Grids also take care of it when we set entry's hexpand to true. But, when using layout (my case) it does not expand to take the the whole space available even when hexpand is true and I had to do it with `gtk_entry_set_width_chars`. So, there is my problem if there is too much code to see here.